# Having difficulties dereferencing a pointer in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am tasked with an assignment to write a program that asks a user how much money they have to spend and then asks the user how many tickets they want to purchase. I must have a main() function and a PurchaseTickets() function. I am new to pointers and am getting quite confused with how to use them with assigning local variables and using those local variables with computations. Could I get some insight into where I am going wrong, and how to make this into a usable program?

EDIT: there must be two functions: main and purchase tickets. using a pointer for the variable remaining cash is necessary, and the program must return 0 if the user does not have enough money to purchase the tickets.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ADULT_TICKET_PRICE 69.00                                                    //define constants
#define CHILD_TICKET_PRICE 35.00

int PurchaseTickets(double *pRemainingCash, int adultTickets, int childTickets);    //declare function PurchaseTickets()

int main(void)
{
    double funds;
    int childTickets;
    int adultTickets;

    printf("How much money do you have to purchase tickets?\n");
    if(scanf("%lf", &funds) != 1)                        //check for errors in user input
    {
        printf("Invalid input, exiting program.\n");
        return 1;                                       //will exit program if invalid characters are entered
    }

    printf("How many child tickets would you like to purchase?\n");
    if(scanf("%d", &childTickets) != 1)                 //check for errors in user input
    {
        printf("Invalid input, exiting program.\n");
        return 1;                                       //will exit program if invalid characters are entered
    }

    printf("How many adult tickets would you like to purchase?\n");
    if(scanf("%d", &adultTickets) != 1)                 //check for errors in user input
    {
        printf("Invalid input, exiting program.\n");
        return 1;                                       //will exit program if invalid characters are entered
    }

    double *pfunds = &funds;

    PurchaseTickets(pfunds, adultTickets, childTickets);

    return 0;
}

/*****************************************************************************************
 *
 *  Function:  PurchaseTickets()
 *
 *  Parameters:
 *
 *      pRemainingCash - points to a variable containing the amt of cash from user
 *      adultTickets - specifies the number of adult tickets the user wants to buy
 *      childTickets - specifies the number of child tickets the user wants to buy
 *
 *  Description: 
 *
 *      The function will determind if the user has enough money to purchase the
 *      specified number of tickets. If they do, the function deducts the proper funds
 *      from their remaining cash and returns the total number of tickets purchased.
 *      if they do not the function returns 0.
 *
*****************************************************************************************/

int PurchaseTickets(double *pRemainingCash, int adultTickets, int childTickets)
{
    double adultCost = (adultTickets * ADULT_TICKET_PRICE);
    double childCost = (childTickets * CHILD_TICKET_PRICE);
    double totalCost = adultCost + childCost;

    int totalTickets = adultTickets + childTickets;

    double remainingCash = *pRemainingCash;
    pRemainingCash = &remainingCash;

    pRemainingCash = remainingCash - totalCost;


    if (*pRemainingCash >= totalCost)
    {
        printf("You have purchased %d tickets, and you have %.2f remaining.",totalTickets, pRemainingCash);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("You do not have enough money to purchase the tickets.");
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `PurchaseTickets` function there are a few problems.

```
double remainingCash = *pRemainingCash;
pRemainingCash = &remainingCash;
```

This code makes a copy of the value `pRemainingCash` points to and then points it at the local copy. This code is correct but it doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

```
pRemainingCash = remainingCash - totalCost;
```

This is where you run into an error due to syntax. It is trying to assign a floating point value to a pointer instead of what the pointer points to. For that you need `*pRemainingCash = remainingCash - totalCost;`

That will solve the error but not the problem because it is modifying the local copy rather than the value that was passed in.

The other issue is that you should check if they can afford the tickets before subtracting the cost. I would expect that if the cost is more than the available funds that you'd leave the available funds unchanged.

Here's a cleaned up version:

```
int PurchaseTickets(double *pRemainingCash, int adultTickets, int childTickets)
{
    double adultCost = (adultTickets * ADULT_TICKET_PRICE);
    double childCost = (childTickets * CHILD_TICKET_PRICE);

    double totalCost = adultCost + childCost;
    int totalTickets = adultTickets + childTickets;

    if (*pRemainingCash >= totalCost)
    {
        // Subtract cost here
        *pRemainingCash -= totalCost;
        // Note *pRemainingCash in the next line. 
        // You need to dereference to obtain the value pointed at.
        printf("You have purchased %d tickets, and you have %.2f remaining.",
            totalTickets, *pRemainingCash);

        // Return success
        return totalTickets;
    }
    // This code won't be reached in the success case because of the return.
    // Removing the else avoids the possibility of the compiler warning that
    // all paths do not return a value.
    printf("You do not have enough money to purchase the tickets.");
    return 0;
}
```

One other minor suggestion in `main`.

Instead of `double *pfunds = &funds;` just call the function like `PurchaseTickets(&funds, adultTickets, childTickets);`

What you have works, but I think it is better to not create an additional variable just for that. If there was more code after that it could be confusing which one to use.

Answer (score 4):

This is a muddle. Without repeating the comments made by @NoDakker, below is an abbreviated version of the code showing the operations required. Note that some variables have been renamed (and comments removed) to increase clarity.

```
// heading stuff omitted for brevity
int main(void)
{
    double funds;
    int childTickets;
    int adultTickets;

    /* Get funds */ // omitted for brevity

    /* Get # of Child tickets */

    /* Get # of Adult tickets */

    int totTckts = PurchaseTickets( &funds, adultTickets, childTickets );

    // Notice that the function performs its task.
    // Reporting those results belongs in the calling function
    if( totTckts )
        printf( "%d tickets, and you have %.2f remaining.", totTckts, funds );
    else
        printf( "Insufficient funds to purchase those tickets." );

    return 0;
}

int PurchaseTickets( double *pFunds, int nAdult, int nChild )
{
    double Cost
        = (nAdult * ADULT_TICKET_PRICE)
        + (nChild * CHILD_TICKET_PRICE);

    if( *pFunds < Cost ) // Insufficient available funds?
        return 0; // no show

    *pFunds -= Cost; // subtract cost from "double funds;" variable in main()

    return nAdult + nChild; // return # of purchased tickets
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your input! I am quite new to C and definitely still learning. Thank you for the help! I think that my code became muddled once my misunderstanding of pointers had me creating variables that were incorrectly used / not necessary.

Comment: I once worked with a fellow who seemed to think that he was "paid by the pound" for the amount of code he typed... Adding more variables, using long-ish names, and useless comments (like "_will exit program if invalid characters are entered_") only make your code harder to read (for us, and for you...) Correct, clean, crisp and clear are the desired adjectives.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand how redundant my comments are now lol. All of my instructors remind us(students) to consistently comment in our code, which I think made me over-comment and I did not consider the effect it had on an overall clean program. I will be more selective in my commenting in the future!

Comment: In "The Elements of Programming Style" the authors cite an instance in a Fortran program where a 4 line comment explained the absence of "END" to mark the end of some program source code... Assume that your readers are familiar with C, but may want to know _why_ certain choices have been made in the code... _Why_, not _what_. Best wishes for your future... (PS: Choosing 4 lines of comment over "END" was a **bad** choice...)

Comment: @LeilaJones You'll get better at commenting the more you code. I tend to write a lot while writing the code because I make a sort of outline to break down the task and then code around that but I'm better at cleaning that up once I'm done now. You learn which are important when you go back to code you've written before and don't understand why you did something a certain way. Explaining why you did something is good but the code should be enough to explain the how. Luckily you get better at naming things consistently the more you code too.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Hear hear!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed your code, and from what I could see as the desired solution, pointers really are not needed for the context of this program's purpose.  First off, since the "PurchaseTickets" function is not really returning any needed information, it makes more sense to set it up with a void return entry.  Second, since the needed input variables for the function can just be all passed as values, there really is no need for sending pointer references.

To minimally effect the minimum changes to your code, the following statements could be commented out in your function along with the refactoring of the "printf" statement.

```
    //double remainingCash = *pRemainingCash;           // Not needed
    //pRemainingCash = &remainingCash;

    //pRemainingCash = remainingCash - totalCost;


    if (*pRemainingCash >= totalCost)
    {
        printf("You have purchased %d tickets, and you have %.2f remaining.",totalTickets, *pRemainingCash - totalCost);    // Note remainder calculation
    }
```

That produced the following test output at the terminal.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/TicketPurchase/bin/Release$ ./TicketPurchase 
How much money do you have to purchase tickets?
800
How many child tickets would you like to purchase?
4
How many adult tickets would you like to purchase?
4
You have purchased 8 tickets, and you have 384.00 remaining.
```

Noting the observations of the code and simplifying things, following is a refactored version of your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ADULT_TICKET_PRICE 69.00                                                    //define constants
#define CHILD_TICKET_PRICE 35.00

void PurchaseTickets(double pRemainingCash, int adultTickets, int childTickets);    //declare function PurchaseTickets()

int main(void)
{
    double funds;
    int childTickets;
    int adultTickets;

    printf("How much money do you have to purchase tickets? ");
    if(scanf("%lf", &funds) != 1)                       //check for errors in user input
    {
        printf("Invalid input, exiting program.\n");
        return 1;                                       //will exit program if invalid characters are entered
    }

    printf("How many child tickets would you like to purchase? ");
    if(scanf("%d", &childTickets) != 1)                 //check for errors in user input
    {
        printf("Invalid input, exiting program.\n");
        return 1;                                       //will exit program if invalid characters are entered
    }

    printf("How many adult tickets would you like to purchase? ");
    if(scanf("%d", &adultTickets) != 1)                 //check for errors in user input
    {
        printf("Invalid input, exiting program.\n");
        return 1;                                       //will exit program if invalid characters are entered
    }

    PurchaseTickets(funds, adultTickets, childTickets);

    return 0;
}

/*****************************************************************************************
 *
 *  Function:  PurchaseTickets()
 *
 *  Parameters:
 *
 *      pRemainingCash - points to a variable containing the amt of cash from user
 *      adultTickets - specifies the number of adult tickets the user wants to buy
 *      childTickets - specifies the number of child tickets the user wants to buy
 *
 *  Description:
 *
 *      The function will determind if the user has enough money to purchase the
 *      specified number of tickets. If they do, the function deducts the proper funds
 *      from their remaining cash and returns the total number of tickets purchased.
 *      if they do not the function returns 0.
 *
*****************************************************************************************/

void PurchaseTickets(double pRemainingCash, int adultTickets, int childTickets)
{
    double adultCost = (adultTickets * ADULT_TICKET_PRICE);
    double childCost = (childTickets * CHILD_TICKET_PRICE);
    double totalCost = adultCost + childCost;

    int totalTickets = adultTickets + childTickets;

    pRemainingCash -= totalCost;

    if (pRemainingCash >= 0.00)
    {
        printf("You have purchased %d tickets, and you have %.2f remaining.\n",totalTickets, pRemainingCash);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("You do not have enough money to purchase the tickets.\n");
    }

    return;
}
```

Note the following refinements:

- The return value for the "PurchaseTickets" function was changed to "void" since there appears to be no use for an integer return value.
- All variables are passed as values in lieu of using any variable pointers.
- Unneeded variables were removed to simplify calculations and comparisons.

With those refinements, following was a series of additional tests of the program and the ticket purchase function.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/TicketPurchase/bin/Release$ ./TicketPurchase 
How much money do you have to purchase tickets? 300.00
How many child tickets would you like to purchase? 4
How many adult tickets would you like to purchase? 4
You do not have enough money to purchase the tickets.
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/TicketPurchase/bin/Release$ ./TicketPurchase 
How much money do you have to purchase tickets? 600
How many child tickets would you like to purchase? 4
How many adult tickets would you like to purchase? 4
You have purchased 8 tickets, and you have 184.00 remaining.
```

To recap, there will be valid reasons to pass variable addresses in lieu of variable values within functions, but one should always be cognizant of the context of the function to determine whether or not that is necessary.  It probably would be wise to seek out additional tutorials on the definition of functions as to when pointers are beneficial.

Comment: Yes, the pointer for the remaining cash variable is required for the assignment, I apologize for the confusion! I will edit the main post to make the assignment requirements are more clear. I still appreciate the input, as it allows me a better starting point to continue to try to figure out the pointers!